# Are there any records of the travel times of 17th century Dutch Beurtvaart?

Tags: 17th-century, travel, netherlands, rivers

Are there any records of how long an average a trip on Dutch inland waterways took.

> *[[Beurtvaart]](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Beurtvaart)* was a Dutch line shipping system for (mostly) inland navigation, that existed from the late 15th century. It was a form of packet trade and a precursor of public transport. The beurtships transported passengers, livestock and freight along fixed routes at fixed prices.

I am particularly interested in finding out how long a trip between the Dutch cities of Vlissingen and Schoonhoven would've taken in the second half of the 17th century, but any data would be helpful.